# Jplayer video with mp4 doesn't work with flash fallback in Opera / FF / IE

Tags: html, flash, video, jplayer

I have this problem with the video on my site as you can see in this link:
http://video.resursecrestine.ro/predici/103445/nastere-din-nou-credinta-dragoste-in-aceasta-ordine

It's working just fine in Chrome but not in any other browser. I know Chrome has native HTML5 support for mp4, but the other browsers should fallback to flash and they don't.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4v: "http://www.resursecrestine.ro/download/41293"
                });
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "m4v",
            size: {
                width: "580px",
                height: "360px",
                cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
            }
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-360p">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
        <div class="jp-gui">
            <div class="jp-video-play">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-video-play-icon" tabindex="1">play</a>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-interface">
                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                <div class="jp-controls-holder">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                        <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="jp-toggles">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-full-screen" tabindex="1" title="full screen">full screen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-restore-screen" tabindex="1" title="restore screen">restore screen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is sending the video with a `text/plain` MIME type, instead of `video/mp4`. According to the [jPlayer Developer Guide](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response), this is a common cause of problems that affect only Firefox and Opera.

Comment: AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm

Comment: The (nginx) server streaming the video in the link you provided (78.46.49.44) is still sending `text/html` (along with a malformed `Content-Disposition: : attachment;` header), although it appears the video is playing correctly now, so I suppose the MIME wasn't your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems using the flash solution. Make sure that your metadata is at the beginning of the video. To do so you can use this free tool:

http://rndware.info/products/metadata-mover.html

Comment: The problem is that the flash solution is not even kicking in, it still uses the HTML solution and only audio is decoded, video remains blank. Any other ideas?